# HTML form with intermediate web service service call before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML form to update the address in the account that submits to a Java servlet.

The problem is that, the form should not accept free flowing address text. Instead the user should enter the zip code/house number/street name, and hit a search button.

This search needs to go to a webservice, perform authentication and get a list of valid addresses that match the search criteria.

This list of addresses should be displayed to the user in the same form (either unhide a hidden element or use a modal dialog), so the user can pick his address.

Only after the valid address is picked, the user should be able to hit the form submit button which sends the data back to the servlet.

I am not sure how to have these 2 buttons do different actions in the form. I am very new to JavaScript and any pointers or examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your webservice build an output of the values based on a search result (a basic string).  Put this data in a JSON statement or just a javascript array.

Return something that looks like this.
     ['SearchResult1', 'SearchResult2', 'SearchREsult3']

On your search box.  Bind a function on change or blur.

```
$('#SearchBox').bind('change', function(){

   var val = $(this).val();
   //Please reference the Jquery Ajax function as im typing this from memory and i always mix one or two things up :).
   $.ajax({
     "type" : "post",
     "url"     : "yoururlhere",
     "data"    : { "search":val },
     success   : function(dataset){

        //When it comes back here check to see if its valid data etc etc

        //After you validate you can populate a picklist on the page with the values.  Or do anything you want with the values like this

        for(x in dataset){
           $('#DocumentElement').append('<p>'+ dataset[x] +'</p>');
        }

     }
   });


});
```

This should start you out.  After that you can just do more things on the callback, or modify the dom in a way which suits you better :).